# How to compare twoTimestamps in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, date, authentication, compare, days

Hello i want to compare dates in laravel
please tell me this code is right.
I want to check it before login.

1. When user is registered, user must be deactivated
2. Admin must activate the user: end_date=activated_date +90 days
3. Admin Deactivation : end_date=deactivated_date;
4. if current_date=deactivate_date

```
if ($user->activated_at ->gte(now()->subDays(90)))   
{ 
   return $this->sendError('messages.user_subscription', [], 400); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `$first` is before or after `$second` using:

```
$first->isBefore($second);
```

or vice versa:

```
$first->isAfter($second);
```

And if you need to get calculate difference, you can use below commands for difference in seconds and hours:

```
$first->diffInSeconds($second);
$first->diffInHours($second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you code is correct, if it does not work you have to add activated_at in $dates in User model

```
.....
User extends Model 
{
....
protected $dates = ['activated_at'];
....
/* Or
    protected $casts = [
        'activated_at' => 'datetime'
    ];
*/
```

Comment: if this answer helps you to resolve your problem, may you please mark it a s a solution to help others